# How to synchronize two local Organisation Units in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i have a problem regarding synchronization of two local OU in Active Directory. The Powerhsell code works fine it copies the users and if there is any change in the source ou it also changes in the target ou. But there is a problem with deleting users if in source ou an user is deleted. The shell script creates and instantly deletes the users again.

```
# Benutzer in der CCTV-OU überprüfen und löschen, wenn sie in den Quell-OUs gelöscht wurden
$CCTVUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $TargetOU

foreach ($CCTVUser in $CCTVUsers) {
    $IsDeleted = $true

    foreach ($SourceOU in $SourceOUs) {
        $SourceUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $SourceOU -Properties EmailAddress

        foreach ($SourceUser in $SourceUsers) {
            if ($SourceUser.EmailAddress -eq $CCTVUser.EmailAddress) {
                $IsDeleted = $false
                break
            }
        }

        if (-not $IsDeleted) {
            break
        }
    }

    if ($IsDeleted) {
        Remove-ADUser -Identity $CCTVUser -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host "Benutzer $($CCTVUser.EmailAddress) wurde aus der CCTV-OU gelöscht, da er in den Quell-OUs nicht mehr vorhanden ist."
    }
}
```

How do I get it to synchronize two OUs correctly? Thanks.

Comment: "it copies the users" nothing in the code you've posted copies any user objects

Comment: Its just a bracket of the full shell code. this part should sync two ous and then delete if there is any change in the source ou

Answer (score 0):

If the OUs belong to the same AD Domain, there should be no need to sync users of two OUs

In a multi-DC environment, if an update is made on a DC, other DCs may not have replicated the update (in this case deletion). In the same AD Site replication occurs within DCs in 15 min. by default. If you run your program at a branch AD Site, you should wait until deletion transactions are replicated to the sites. Even your code connects to a specified DC, the protocols may provide referral DCs for the operations, so replication is an important factor.

The sync of OUs in the same AD Domain may also create unexpected problems. For example group policies applying to those OUs, what are the SamAcountName (which must be unique) of the copied users, are the copied users disabled if not does anyone logon using these credentials etc.

If the OUs that is required to sync reside in different Active Directory Forests, then MIM 2016 may be used for directory synchronization, an overview is at the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/microsoft-identity-manager-2016